# Inline Editing But Instance Doesn't Exist

Tags: javascript, ajax, ckeditor

I have my own custom non-jQuery ajax which I use for programming web applications. I recently ran into problems with IE9 using TinyMCE, so am trying to switch to CKeditor

The editable text is being wrapped in a div, like so:

```
<div id='content'>
  <div id='editable' contenteditable='true'>
    page of inline text filled with ajax when links throughout the site are clicked
  </div> 
</div>
```

When I try to getData on the editable content using the examples in the documentation, I get an error.

I do this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editable.getData();
```

And get this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getData' of undefined

So I figure that it doesn't know where the editor is in the dom... I've tried working through all editors to get the editor name, but that doesn't work-- no name appears to be found.

I've tried this:

```
for(var i in CKEDITOR.instances) { 
  alert(CKEDITOR.instances[i].name);
}
```

The alert is just blank-- so there's no name associated with it apparently.

I should also mention, that despite my best efforts, I cannot seem to get the editable text to have a menu appear above it like it does in the [Massive Inline Editing Example](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/13-02-13-08-51/standard/samples/inlineall.html)

Thanks for any assistance you can bring.

Jason Silver

UPDATE:

I'm showing off my lack of knowledge here, but I had never come across "contenteditable='true'" before, so thought that because I was able to type inline, therefore the editor was instantiated somehow... but now I'm wondering if the editor is even being applied to my div.

UPDATE 2:

When the page is loaded and the script is initially called, the div does not exist. The editable div is sent into the DOM using AJAX. @Zee left a comment below that made me wonder if there is some other command that should be called in order to apply the editor to that div, so I created a button in the page with the following onclick as a way to test this approach: (adapted from the ajax example)

```
var editor,html='';config = {};editor=CKEDITOR.appendTo('editable',config, html );
```

That gives the following error in Chrome:

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'equals' of undefined 
>  + CKEDITOR.tools.extend.getEditor ckeditor.js:101
>    b ckeditor.js:252
>    CKEDITOR.appendTo ckeditor.js:257
>    onclick www.pediatricjunction.com:410
```

Am I headed in the right direction? Is there another way to programmatically tell CKEditor to apply the editor to a div?

UPDATE 3:

Thanks to @Reinmar I had something new to try. The most obvious way for me to test to see if this was the solution was to put a button above the content editable div that called CKEDITOR.inlineAll() and inline('editable') respectively:

```
<input type='button' onclick=\"CKEDITOR.inlineAll();\" value='InlineAll'/>
<input type='button' onclick=\"CKEDITOR.inline('editable');\" value='Inline'/>
<input type='button' onclick=\"var editor = CKEDITOR.inline( document.getElementById( 'editable' ) );\" value='getElementById'/>
```

This returned the same type of error in Chrome for all three buttons, namely:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'equals' of undefined ckeditor.js:101
+  CKEDITOR.tools.extend.getEditor ckeditor.js:101
   CKEDITOR.inline ckeditor.js:249
   CKEDITOR.inlineAll ckeditor.js:250
   onclick
```

UPDATE 4:

Upon further fiddling, I've tracked down the problem being related to json2007.js, which is a script I use which works with Real Simple History (RSH.js). These scripts have the purpose of tracking ajax history, so as I move forward and back through the browser, the AJAX page views is not lost.

Here's the fiddle page: http://jsfiddle.net/jasonsilver/3CqPv/2/

Comment: im curious, CKEDITOR.instances.editable doesnt exist, but CKEDITOR.instances[i].name is just empty? If you call CKEDITOR.instances[i].getData(), do you get something? If you dont see the toolbar, then it means that particular div is not inlined, is the autoinlining on? Are those divs present on page before the CKEDITOR is activated?

Comment: I pasted your sample into `inlineall.html` file from CKEditor package and it everything is fine (on Chrome at least). Instance called `editable` exists and works correctly. Could you try to create jsfiddle showing your issue?

Comment: Good point, I should have included the results of getData on instances[i], sorry @Zee. Asking for instances[i].getData causes an error in Chrome

Uncaught TypeError: Object function (w) {
        var a = [],
            k,
            i,
            v;
etc...

Comment: im not familiar with ckeditor but, you added the css of it? Isnt it a plugin for jquery?

Comment: @Ark it's a WYSIWYG editor, and not a plugin. My issues are javascript related, but thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I have tracked down the problem.

The library I was using for tracking Ajax history and remembering commands for the back button, called Real Simple History, was using a script called json2007 which was intrusive and extended native prototypes to the point where things broke.

RSH.js is kind of old, and I wasn't using it to it's full potential anyway, so my final solution was to rewrite the essential code I needed for that, namely, a listener that watched for anchor (hash) changes in the URL, then parsed those changes and resubmitted the ajax command.

```
var current_hash = window.location.hash;
function check_hash() {
    if ( window.location.hash != current_hash ) {
        current_hash = window.location.hash;
        refreshAjax();
    }
}
hashCheck = setInterval( "check_hash()", 50 );
```

'refreshAjax()' was an existing function anyway, so this is actually a more elegant solution than I was using with Real Simple History.

After stripping out the json2007.js script, everything else just worked, and CKEditor is beautiful.

Thanks so much for your help, @Reinmar... I appreciate your patience and effort.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to initialize inline editor there are two ways:

1. If element which is editable (has `contenteditable` attribute) exists when page is loaded CKEditor will automatically initialize an instance for it. Its name will be taken from that element's id or it will be `editor<number>`. You can find editors initialized automatically on [this sample](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/13-02-14-08-51/standard/samples/inlineall.html).
2. If this element is created dynamically, then you need to initialize editor on your own.
   E.g. after appending `<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">X</div>` to the document you should call:

   `CKEDITOR.inline( 'editor' )`

   or

   `CKEDITOR.inlineAll()`

   See [docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-inline) and [docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-inlineAll).
   You can find editor initialized this way on [this sample](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/13-02-14-08-51/standard/samples/inlinebycode.html).

The [`appendTo`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-appendTo) method has different use. You can initialize themed (not inline) editor inside specified element. This method also accepts data of editor (as 3rd arg), when all other methods (`CKEDITOR.inline`, `CKEDITOR.replace`, `CKEDITOR.inlineAll`) take data from the element they are replacing/using.

**Update**

I checked that libraries you use together with CKEditor are poorly written and cause errors you mentioned. Remove `json2007.js` and `rsh.js` and CKEditor works fine.

Comment: Thanks @Reinmar... what other things might I try? This does not seem to have helped (see above).

Comment: As I wrote before - it's hard to guess what you do wrong if you haven't uploaded entire page.

Comment: Not sure if this is appropriate to ask-- but can I pay you to login to my sample site and look at the code? The issue being I need to send you a password but I don't want it here for the world to see.

Comment: Hey @Reinmar, I've created a fiddle (my first time fiddling with Fiddle), and have encountered the same problem. It makes me wonder if there is some conflict in the scripts I use, such as RSH.js (Real Simple History) etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasonsilver/3CqPv/2/

Comment: Ok, I checked that `json2007.js` lib which is required by `rsh.js` is so badly written (it extends native prototypes) that it causes CKEditor's failure. Remove them and everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks for looking @Reinmar. It appears that json2007.js has issues with other javascript applications as well. For example, http://code.google.com/p/flotr/issues/detail?id=36
I wonder if there's any other json parsers I can use in place of json2007? I'll see if I can get support from RSH on this.

Comment: I don't think so. json2007 adds methods to native objects and RSH uses that. You'd have to patch RSH too.